Is a professional path question on topic?
I wanted to ask a question about possible professional paths related to psychology taking into account my background as software developer, but would like to know if the question would be on topic, since it could be seen as work searching advice instead of curiosity to discover which areas or positions could take the most out this 2 areas.

Welcome. Could you add a draft representation of your intended question?

We often refer such questions to Academia.SE - is there a reason why it would not be better posted there?

@ArnonWeinberg We probably shouldn't do that; career questions and recommendations for study are explicitly off-topic at Academia.SE.

It might be on topic, but you would have to make it specific enough to remove multiple different potential subjective answers, and write it in a way so that it does not apply just to you, but others like you who might be in a similar situation.
With this in mind, feel free to post a first attempt on the main site. Do not feel overly discouraged if it would be placed on hold. You can still edit taking feedback into account.

Thanks for asking on Meta.
If your question doesn't ultimately work for the main site, an alternative is to ask in chat to get some input outside the more strict Q&A format of StackExchange.
